# Daily basis I am chanting the maha mrityunjaya mantra with samput

Tags: shiva, bhairava

Only a daily basis I am chanting the maha mrityunjaya mantra with samput does it also worship the bhairva along with shiva or it is totally a different process I have just visited Kal Bhairva temple in Kashi and I am feeling more connected afterward so what is the reason behind it.